# Usar una variable php dentro de una funcion con str_replace

Tags: php

Lo que necesito es reemplazar lo que se encuentra en la variable **($codigo)** por (autitos). Para eso utilizo una funcion con nombre (quitar) utilizando str_replace, el problema es que dentro de la funcion quitar no me reconoce la variable **($codigo) cuando llamo a la funcion**. Espero que se entienda.

```
<?php
    $codigo = "autos";
    function quitar($mensaje){
        $mensaje = str_replace("$codigo","autitos",$mensaje);
        return $mensaje; 
    }

    // llamo a la funcion
    $nombre= quitar($nombre);
?>
```

Comment: Agregando comillas o sin comillas no me funciona? De todas formas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Puedes hacer como @Sr1871, o también puedes pasarle como parámetro al llamar a la función. ¿No te da error en la variable `$nombre`?

Comment: ¿Y por qué utilizar str_replace? Si tienes que sustituir el valor por "autitos" simplemente iguala la variable $codigo = "autitos";

Comment: Se me hace mas facil usar str_replace por eso utilizo este metodo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes que pasar la variable `$codigo` a la función para acceder a su valor desde dentro y llamar a dicha variable sin comillas al hacer el `str_replace`.

El código así funciona:

```
    $codigo = "autos"; 
        function quitar($mensaje,$codigo){ 
          $mensaje = str_replace($codigo,"autitos",$mensaje); 
           return $mensaje; 
        } 
        $nombre= quitar("Este es el día de autos",$codigo); 
        echo $nombre;

 //resultado Este es el día de autitos
```

Comment: Sin duda es mejor opción esta en este caso, dejo la respuesta de todos modos por si a alguien le sirve de la otra forma

Comment: Gracias Carmen este ejemplo me ha servido muy bien, de todas formas agradezco a todos los que participaron en esta pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

para usar variables externas en funciones haz lo siguiente

```
$codigo = "autos";
function quitar($mensaje) use ($codigo){
    $mensaje = str_replace("$codigo","autitos",$mensaje);
    return $mensaje; 
}
```

Comment: Gracias a ambos, pero me parece que tengo un problema de comillas ya que php no me lo ejecuta.

Comment: efectivamente el problema lo tengo al agregar el siguiente fragmento de codigo: use ($codigo1)

Comment: perdon use ($codigo)